# Issue with resume after suspend to disk

Tags: linux, power-management, suspend

I am having an issue with the suspend to disk feature for ARM Linux Kernel version:

Linux 4.2.0-rc3-00115-gc5dfd65-dirty #4 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 24 12:15:54 CEST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

I can suspend to disk fine, however when resuming it hangs at disabling non-boot CPUs and does a reboot after about 10 seconds.

Excerpt from Serial Console when I do "echo disk > /sys/power/state":

```
PM: writing image.
PM: Using 1 thread(s) for compression.
PM: Compressing and saving image data (25080 pages)...
PM: Image saving progress:   0%
PM: Image saving progress:  10%
PM: Image saving progress:  20%
PM: Image saving progress:  30%
PM: Image saving progress:  40%
PM: Image saving progress:  50%
PM: Image saving progress:  60%
PM: Image saving progress:  70%
PM: Image saving progress:  80%
PM: Image saving progress:  90%
PM: Image saving done.
PM: Wrote 100320 kbytes in 3.21 seconds (31.25 MB/s)
PM: S|
reboot: System halted
```

Excerpt from the Serial Console when I do a coldstart:

```
PM: Checking hibernation image partition /dev/mmcblk0p1
PM: Hibernation image partition 179:1 present
PM: Looking for hibernation image.
PM: Image signature found, resuming
PM: Preparing processes for restore.
Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) done.
PM: Loading hibernation image.
PM: Basic memory bitmaps created
PM: Using 1 thread(s) for decompression.
PM: Loading and decompressing image data (24977 pages)...
PM: Image loading progress:   0%
PM: Image loading progress:  10%
PM: Image loading progress:  20%
PM: Image loading progress:  30%
PM: Image loading progress:  40%
PM: Image loading progress:  50%
PM: Image loading progress:  60%
PM: Image loading progress:  70%
PM: Image loading progress:  80%
PM: Image loading progress:  90%
PM: Image loading progress: 100%
PM: Image loading done.
PM: Read 99908 kbytes in 3.42 seconds (29.21 MB/s)
PM: Image successfully loaded
fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: MDIO read timeout
fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: MDIO write timeout
PM: quiesce of devices complete after 74.808 msecs
PM: late quiesce of devices complete after 1.144 msecs
PM: noirq quiesce of devices complete after 25.441 msecs
Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
CPU1: shutdown
--- Here it times out after 10 seconds and does a reboot.
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.